Should one submit to a workshop and a conference at the same time, typically ACL and EMNLP?
I am currently a PhD student in NLP. Say that I submitted my work to ACL, where my paper was rejected for the main conference. Then I submitted to a workshop attached to ACL, for a deadline of June 1st.
However, I worked more on the topic and wish to publish the revised version at EMNLP, whose deadline is on June 16th. After contacting the ARR supports (ACL double submission policy), I have two options:

Submit to the workshop in a non-archival way so that the paper is not included in the proceedings
Withdraw the paper from the workshop if the revised version is accepted at the later conference

For the second option, the notification of acceptance of EMNLP is September 20th. Meanwhile, the ACL workshop is held on August 16th. Then it would be impossible to withdraw the paper from the workshop if it is accepted at EMNLP since it will have been presented.
Does submitting to both venues violate the policies or cause ethical issues? What should I do? What if both the original paper and the revised paper were accepted respectively at the venues?

How different will the EMNLP submission be? Would you have enough new material that you could make it a follow up work (and cite the workshop paper it builds upon)? And why not submit to the workshop in a non-archival way as the organizers suggest?

The revised version should improve the method to the reviewer's concern about the practicality of the proposition. In addition, comparison to more recent methods will also be addressed.

You need to check the specific rules of the specific ACL workshop and EMNLP, the problem is generally during the review process (waste of reviewer time if paper is reviewed concurrently at multiple venues) and paper being accepted (same exact paper cannot be published twice).
If your paper is accepted at the archival track in an ACL workshop, then it cannot be submitted to EMNLP, because it will be published at the ACL workshop and it will be part of the proceedings.
If you submit to a non-archival track, then this is more flexible and opens the chance that you can submit to EMNLP, you just need to confirm that the review process dates do not intersect between both venues (unlikely but still you should check).
I have seen workshops that specifically accept (for non-archival tracks) papers being submitted to other specific conferences, that is why it is important to check the rules of each venue and try to see if a common ground is found.

Thank you for your answer, but what do you mean exactly by "confirm that the review process does not intersect between both venues"

@NguyễnQuangAnh Corrected, I mean that the dates of the review process do not intersect.

As stated the review process for the workshops ends on June 20th and for the later conference, the review process is from June 15th. So this overlapping means that the paper cannot be submitted to EMNLP if the reviewing for the workshop has not ended, even as a non archival submission?

@qan In this case I would ask the workshop organizers if they are ok with this due to the non-archival track.

Even though the conferences ask the authors for to check for double session, it is very rare they practically check that. As there is no way to check where the paper has been submitted before the conference date or when it appears online. So, even if both papers are accepted, you are in a better position to choose to publish in a better conference and withdraw from another one. This is what most of MS/PhD students do in the academic world.

This is highly unethical and directly violates dual submission policies of most venues, and not at all "what most of MS/PhD students do" in my experience.

The academic world is not so fair and transparent as it should be. I don't know where on Earth you are and what practices are followed in your region. But I have spent more than a decade in academia and am well aware of such (mal)practices. Most MS/PhD students are after getting more and more publications in their resumes, and, they want to try their luck everywhere if they are not well guided by their supervisors. I know this "highly unethical" but this is the reality.

Do not follow this advice, it is terrible, reviewers and organizers are very common between both conferences, so if reviewers or organizers notice the double submission, the punishment will not only be rejection in both venues, you could get banned from future conferences. This is not a common practice in NLP/ML as this answer is suggesting. I have noticed double submissions to conferences I have reviewed for.
